# Place breakpoints at all referenced locations in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, add-in, breakpoints, find-all-references

The "Find All References" option in the VS editor helps us in finding the locations where a specific object is used. But is there any way so that I can automatically place a break-point at all those locations? Placing break-points for an object referenced at say 100 locations sees impossible! Is there any tool/addin out there which does this job?

Comment: Why? Place a breakpoint at the start of the referenced function, when it hits, take a look at the call stack window to see who called it (and you can double click on the line to go to the code).

Comment: @Oded: I'm not debugging any method. I'm debugging for an object which becomes null in some cases in my code, and I want to check where & why it's becoming so.

Comment: If you are not debugging, why place breakpoints?